# Since Win 10 Creators Update (1703), maximized windows sometimes get bigger than the desktop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, window, windows-10-v1703

I have Windows 10 and recently got the Creators Update, so now `winver` reports "Version 1703 (Build 15063.0)". I am running it on a Dell notebook with two external monitors connected. My Task bars are docked to the left border of each screen and are fixed and do not get hidden at any time.

The problem I am experiencing is that sometimes when I want to maximize a window, it does not grow to the desktop size (monitor size minus task bar), but the full monitor size. The extra part is then either on the left, behind my task bar, or on the right, outside of the monitor.

When I unmaximize the window after that, it keeps its size. To temporarily fix the behaviour and maximize the window correctly, I have to manually shrink the unmaximized window's width to fit on the desktop and then maximize it again.

Is this a bug in the Creators Update? Are there any known workarounds or fixes?

Comment: There are files kept by programs which specify the size at which they run. I know that CCleaner can delete those files to reset the window size. To clarify, which applications are the culprits?

Comment: @GeorgeTian It happened with various applications, I don't think it is specific to any. Some examples are Firefox, Source Tree, Adobe Reader.

Comment: Try searching for 'change window size', there are a few similar posts in SE and Google. The problem shouldn't be due to the Windows update. Also, try testing to see whether only using 1 monitor also creates different window sizes.

Comment: @GeorgeTian That query wasn't really helpful. So far I did not observe the problem without external monitors, but I also did never observe it with the external monitors before the update.